# How do I widen one column in a SharePoint WebPart?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a WebPart on my SharePoint page which contains five columns. It's not a list item and I don't want to widen the entire webpart just one column which happens to be the first column.

Does anyone know how to do this? I feel as though this is something simple I'm missing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can add some javascript code on your page, then you can make column wider by javascript.
Something like this:

```
var table = document.querySelector('.ms-listviewtable');
var head = table.firstChild.firstChild;
head.childNodes[1].style.width="500px";
```